# WPF Databinding Combobox <-> Application-Settings

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox, settings, application-settings

For my wpfapplication I added a settings file, which contains a Color as setting :

MySetting.settings

```
Name      Type                         Value
myColor   System.Windows.Media.Color   #FFFFFF
```

So my auto generated code looks like :

MySettings.Desinger.cs

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("#FFFFFFFF")]
    public global::System.Windows.Media.Color myColor {
        get {
            return ((global::System.Windows.Media.Color)(this["myColor"]));
        }
        set {
            this["myColor"] = value;
        }
    }
```

This value I want to set on a config window. This is my xaml code :

configWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="myApp.configWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:myApp.Properties"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:myApp.Converter"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"      
    Title="myApp" Height="557" Width="626">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <converter:myColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
    <properties:MySettings x:Key="config"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{x:Type Colors}" MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Height="524" Width="615" DataContext="{StaticResource config}">
    <TabControl Height="508" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="616" BorderThickness="0" Margin="1,11,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="options" Name="tabItemOptions">
            <Grid Height="484">
                <GroupBoxHeight="330" Margin="6,149,15,0" Name="groupBox2" >
                    <Grid Height="313">
                        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxMyColor" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Default.myColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Background="{Binding Path=Name}" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=comboBoxNotificationColor}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=comboBoxNotificationColor}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

But if I try to change the color, I'm able to select a value (e.g. "White") on combobox, but the config is never changed. When I set a breakpoint on `MySettings.Desinger.cs -> myCOlor -> set { ... }`, it's never reached.
Where is my fault?

Comment: Is the `ConvertBack` being called in your colorConverter?

Comment: Yes, the convert and convertback is called

Answer (score 1):

You're missing INotifyPropertyChanged in my opinion.

Without it your model or viewmodel can't notify when you change something from ui.

Information about this in here: [WPF-INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: Are u think I need this? Cause for other Controls like a Slider or a Checkbox it works...